# Abbreviated time zone regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need regex for taking abbreviated time zone in date object

Example: "Thu Oct 08 2015 20:03:40 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

Expected:"Thu Oct 08 2015 20:03:40 GMT+0530 (IST)"

```
var str = new Date().toString().match(/\(([A-Za-z\s].*)\)/)[1] 
var newmsg = str.replace(/[a-z\s]/g, ''); 
console.log(newmsg);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vx7yshc2/)**

Please suggestion some better regex

Comment: Do you really need a regex, or are you looking for a way to get the standard abbreviation of the user's time zone? The capital letters in the time zone's name will often not match the time zone's abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`console.log( new Date().toString().replace(/\(([A-Z]).*?\s([A-Z]).*?\s([A-Z]).*?\)/,'($1$2$3)'));`

I'm assuming here that there are always 3 words, and they start with capital letters.

Comment: It's also not a good assumption that leaving the initial capital letters, and removing the rest, is actually a correct thing to do to convert long forms to short forms. But it might be good enough for the (limited) purpose.

Comment: [for instance, here in the UK, "GMT Standard Time" gets converted by this to GST, which means Gulf Standard Time. But this is a question about regex, not time zones, so I answered it in that spirit]

Comment: Agreed, as you can also see from the first page of that same link.

Comment: This question is indeed about regex, but it probably [should not have been](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/217642).